# FCC Refactor Global Variables Out of Functions, array is not using both methods used together

Tags: javascript, arrays

working my way through the new FCC material. Definitely having trouble in parts. This one I've gotten close, but it's still wrong because it doesn't pass the final test:

"newestBookList should equal ["The Hound of the Baskervilles", "Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica", "Disquisitiones Arithmeticae", "A Brief History of Time"]"

When I console.log(newestBookList), I see it's removing the correct entry but not adding "Brief History". Any suggestions? I'm not clear on why both methods work individually but not together here nor how to use BDD to test for that...

```
// the global variable
var bookList = ["The Hound of the Baskervilles", "On The Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies", "Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica", "Disquisitiones Arithmeticae"];

/* This function should add a book to the list and return the list */
// New parameters should come before the bookName one

// Add your code below this line
function add(arr, bookName) {
  return arr.concat([bookName]);
}

  // Add your code above this line

/* This function should remove a book from the list and return the list */
// New parameters should come before the bookName one

// Add your code below this line
function remove(arr, bookName) {
  if (bookList.indexOf(bookName) >= 0) {
    var index = bookList.indexOf(bookName);
    return bookList.slice(0, index).concat(bookList.slice(index + 1));
    // Add your code above this line
  }
}

var newBookList = add(bookList, 'A Brief History of Time');
var newerBookList = remove(bookList, 'On The Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies');
var newestBookList = remove(add(bookList, 'A Brief History of Time'), 'On The Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies');

//console.log(bookList);
//console.log(newBookList);
//console.log(newerBookList);
console.log(newestBookList);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `remove` function is referencing the *original* `bookList`, not the passed array. Change all `bookList` references to `arr` references (the parameter passed to the `remove` function):

```js
// the global variable
var bookList = ["The Hound of the Baskervilles", "On The Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies", "Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica", "Disquisitiones Arithmeticae"];

/* This function should add a book to the list and return the list */
// New parameters should come before the bookName one

// Add your code below this line
function add(arr, bookName) {
  return arr.concat([bookName]);
}

  // Add your code above this line

/* This function should remove a book from the list and return the list */
// New parameters should come before the bookName one

// Add your code below this line
function remove(arr, bookName) {
  if (arr.indexOf(bookName) >= 0) {
    var index = arr.indexOf(bookName);
    return arr.slice(0, index).concat(arr.slice(index + 1));
    // Add your code above this line
  } else console.log('n');
}

var newBookList = add(bookList, 'A Brief History of Time');
var newerBookList = remove(bookList, 'On The Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies');
const added = add(bookList, 'A Brief History of Time');
var newestBookList = remove(added, 'On The Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies');

//console.log(bookList);
// console.log(newBookList);
//console.log(newerBookList);
console.log(newestBookList);
```

Though, you might consider checking the `indexOf` only once:

```
function remove(arr, bookName) {
  var index = arr.indexOf(bookName);
  if (index === -1) return;
  return [...arr.slice(0, index), ...arr.slice(index + 1)];
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for catching that! Obvious mistake.